# Newsstand application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have one application in iTunes which download books and magazines from server. I have integrated Non-consumable IAP for every books and magazines. Now, I want to integrate Newsstand to application. For that I need to integrate at least one subscription to application. I am confusing how to manage it? How can application get idea that any user has subscripted for that IAP or not?

How server will allow any particular device to download new subscription ?

Answer (score 1):

A user buys a new subscription the same way he buys a standard IAP.

After the purchase you will get a receipt (in iOS < 7) or an entry in the App Receipt (iOS >= 7) that tells you when the subscription was bought and when it expires.

When a new issue is available, (or when a user restores his purchases etc) you will need to check that information and determine if his subscription is valid and provide him with the issues he has subscribed for.

Your server can store device tokens and the base64-encoded receipt to know which users are valid subscribers.

That's the really really really basic info on newsstand and subscriptions. There is much to read and learn in the documentation pages and in Stackoverflow.

I would suggest reading through the tutorials 1 and 2 listed below FIRST. They are a bit outdated now but they will give you a more clear view of what is ahead of you.

[Subscription Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html)

[Newsstand notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2280/_index.html)

[Tutorial 1](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial/)

[Tutorial 2](http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/29/at-newsstand-and-subscriptions/)